# SVG into a button | Typescript & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, styled-components, storybook

I want to put an SVG element on a button and when the mouse is over it it changes color along with the background. However, I have not been able to achieve it. Do you think you can help me? I'm using Storybook to see how the button is turning out. The SVG has to be inside the project files

thank you so much!

```
//socialMediaButton.component.tsx

import {FC} from 'react';
import {ButtonProps, StyledButton} from './socialMediaButton.styles';

export const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ ...props}) => {
  return <StyledButton {...props}></StyledButton>;
};
```

```
//socialMediaButton.stories.tsx

import {ComponentStory, ComponentMeta} from '@storybook/react';

import {Button} from './socialMediaButton.component';

export default {
  title: 'Atoms/SocialMediaButton',
  component: Button,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Button>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

export const InstagramButton = Template.bind({});
InstagramButton.args = {
  variant: 'light',
};

export const FacebookButton = Template.bind({});
FacebookButton.args = {
  variant: 'light',
};

export const TwitterButton = Template.bind({});
TwitterButton.args = {
  variant: 'light',
};
```

```
socialMediaButton.styles.jsx

import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';
import {ReactNode} from 'react';

export interface ButtonProps {
  variant?: 'light' | 'dark';
}

const variants = {
  light: css`
    background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.darkBackgroundColor};
    color: ${({theme}) => theme.lightIconColor};

    &:hover,
    &:active {
      background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.lightBackgroundColor};
      color: ${({theme}) => theme.darkBackgroundColor};
    }
  `,
  dark: css`
    background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.lightBackgroundColor};
    color: ${({theme}) => theme.darkBackgroundColor};
    &:hover,
    &:active {
      background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.darkBackgroundColor};
      color: ${({theme}) => theme.lightBackgroundColor};
    }
  `,
};

export const StyledButton = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  ${({variant}) => variants[variant || 'light']}

  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: none;
  padding: 2em 2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: All 300ms ease;

`;
```

I would like to send different icons of the different social networks and have the component ready

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDEFF.png)

Comment: are you set the `stroke` in the SVG file to `currentColor`?

Comment: I don't know how to add a SVG :')